# Replacing certain values with function in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, csv, notepad

My `.csv` file contains a lot of the following: `"123",bpm`
The value is changing, so it's not always 123, but it's always three digits. I would like to change all of these three digit values with 10 lower values. How do I do that?

Example:
this is part of a line:

```
"323",watts,unknown,"3274",,unknown,"2084",,heart_rate,"154",bpm,cadence,"70",rpm,temperature,"15",C,left_torque_effectiveness,
```

and I would expect this:

```
"323",watts,unknown,"3274",,unknown,"2084",,heart_rate,"144",bpm,cadence,"70",rpm,temperature,"15",C,left_torque_effectiveness,
```

And if it's not 154, but 133, I would like 123 instead, so on and so on. So always 10 lower.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1545007/edit) and add sample lines and expected result. What do you mean by “change all of these three digit values with 10 lower values”

Comment: if it's always the same column, it is much more convenient to use a CSV edit dedicated tool

Answer (score 1):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `calculate.py`):

```
import re
def calculate(match):
    return '"%s' % (str(int(match.group(1)) - 10))

editor.rereplace('"(\d+)(?=",bpm)', calculate)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> calculate)
- Done

**Regex explanation:**

```
"               # a double quote
(\d+)           # group 1, 1 or more digits
(?=",bpm)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have after: ",bpm
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]